# Running Windows Installer in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, windows-installer, safe-mode

When Windows 10 is started in safe mode, windows installer is not normally available.

I would like to be able to run windows installer in safe mode, to test a setup program which crashes in standard mode.

Several sites give registry changes which allow this. For example:

- [Symantec - Windows Installer & Safe Mode](https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/windows-installer-safe-mode)
- [North Carolina State University - Installing Programs in Safe Mode](https://www.itecs.ncsu.edu/helpdesk/kb/installing-programs-in-safe-mode/)

Are there any issues in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes in registry to make windows installer work in a safe mode. Here is the article with the details you need to change. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-installer-work-in-safe-mode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @moni9 I asked "Are there any issues in doing this?". My question already included links to sites which describe the registry changes.